# Repeat rows with in the GROUP as per max value of that group using SQL (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, repeat, group

Input

| question_id | option_rank |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

How to get below output using SQL. Position will be new fabricated column in the output. Basically a given option rank to be repeated n times, n being max option rank of a given question.

| question_id | option_rank | position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 |

Created numbers table with single column consisting of id from 1 to 1000(1000 rows) and then joined it with above question table.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a self join here:

```sql
SELECT t1.question_id, t1.option_rank, t2.option_rank AS position
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.question_id = t1.question_id
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
```